# Application icon does not appearing on the search result page

Tags: facebook, search

I created application and uploaded icon for it but the icon does not appear on search result page:

http://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=Gammafish%20Poker&type=apps

What should I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

The image that is displayed in that search results page is not the icon.

In the apps settings page, where you can change the icon, there's also the "profile pic" (or what ever they call it), hover the mouse over it, you'll see that the text "edit" is then showing on the image, click it and upload the image you want to be displayed as the app "profile pic", then you should see it in those search results.

---

## Edit

I checked a bit more, I was wrong, the image in the search results is not the "app profile pic", that is being displayed (for example) if you hover the text link.

I'm not 100%, but it looks like that pic in the search results is taken from the app page, for us it uses an old profile picture of the app page.
You can set up the "App Page" in the app settings, the "Advanced" tab, the last item.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded both images (icon and "profile pic"). But no one is displayed on search result page. This is strange behavior, because "profile pic" is visible on the search tooltip while you print this query in the search text box

Comment: It has app page with picture but it is not displayed for application it is displayed for the page only in the search results.